# Approximation used in Hutton's computation in the Schiehallion experiment

Tags: multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory

I have been trying to understand the numerical integration approach employed by Charles Hutton in calculating the gravitational attraction of the Schiehallion mountain on a plumb line. The paper is available here: https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstl.1778.0034. In the paper, he provides a geometric argument and I'm trying to formulate it in terms of calculus. The relevant pages (if you are interested) are 750-755.

The basic approach can be seen in the following diagram:

[image]

The plumb line is at A in the figure. He is using cylindrical coordinates to do the integration. He takes the meridian going toward north to be the positive X-axis and computes the X-component of the gravitational attraction of each mass element on the plumb line. If you have a mass element enclosed in the ring between $r = r_1$ and $r = r_2$, and the sector between $\theta = \theta_1$ and $\theta = \theta_2$ and planes $z = 0$ and $z = h$, the X-component of its gravitational attraction would be:

$$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\int_{0}^{h}\int_{r_1}^{r_2} Gm\rho\;\frac{r^2}{(r^2 + z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}\;\cos{\theta}\;dr\;d\theta\;dz$$

Here, $G$ is the gravitational constant, $m$ is the mass of the plumb bob and $\rho$ is the density of the mountain.

The integral (if you factor out $Gm\rho$) evaluates to:

$$h\;(\sin{\theta_2} - \sin{\theta_1})\;\Biggl\{\log\Biggl(\sqrt{\frac{r_2^2}{h^2} + 1} + \frac{r_2}{h}\Biggr) - \log\Biggl(\sqrt{\frac{r_1^2}{h^2} + 1} + \frac{r_1}{h}\Biggr)\Biggr\}$$

(I hope I have calculated the integral correctly.)

He seems to be assuming that $r_2$ is close to $r_1$ and $h \ll \frac{r_1 + r_2}{2}$. With these assumptions, it seems to me that the following approximation should hold:

$$\Biggl\{\log\Biggl(\sqrt{\frac{r_2^2}{h^2} + 1} + \frac{r_2}{h}\Biggr) - \log\Biggl(\sqrt{\frac{r_1^2}{h^2} + 1} + \frac{r_1}{h}\Biggr)\Biggr\} \approx \frac{r_2 - r_1}{\sqrt{(\frac{r_1 + r_2}{2})^2 + h^2}}$$

But I'm unable to see how to derive this approximation. I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide in helping me understand this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your integral development of Hutton's gravitational attraction of the mountain, you have the attraction in the $X$-direction as
$$ 
\text{Attraction}=\int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}\int_{0}^{h}\int_{r_{1}}^{r_{2}} Gm\rho \,\dfrac{r^2}{\left(r^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}\, \cos\theta\, {\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta\,{\rm d}z.
$$
On setting $Gm\rho=1$, this integrates to $h\left(\sin\theta_{2}-\sin\theta_{1}\right)I$,
where Hutton's  mean radius to the center of the "finite element" is $r_{m}=\left(r_{1}+r_{2}\right)/2$ and $I\,$ is the expression that you wish to approximate. We may now relate the inner and outer radii of the element by means of the relations $r_{1}=r_{m}-\varepsilon$ and   $r_{2}=r_{m}+\varepsilon$, where, from the last relation,
$$
\varepsilon=r_{2}-r_{m}=r_{2}-\left(r_{1}+r_{2}\right)/2=\left(r_{2}-r_{1}\right)/2.
$$

With these expressions, together with the relation $\log(a)-\log(b)=\log(a/b)$, we can now write your Hutton $X$-attraction integral as
$$
I=\log\left(\dfrac{H\left(r_{2}\right)}{H\left(r_{1}\right)}\right)
= \log\left(\dfrac{H\left(r_{m}+\varepsilon\right)}{H\left(r_{m}-\varepsilon\right)}\right)
$$
where
$$
H(r)=\dfrac{1}{h}\left\{\sqrt{r^2+h^2}+r\right\}.
$$
Expanding $H\left( r_{m}+\varepsilon\right)$ in a Taylor series and keeping only the linear term in $\varepsilon$, that is we are assuming that $r_{2}-r_{1}\ll 2\, r_{m}$, gives the approximate relation
$$
H\left(r_{m}+ \varepsilon\right)\approx 
H\left(r_{m}\right)
+\varepsilon \left( \dfrac{{\rm d}H}{{\rm d}r} \right)_{r=r_{m}}.
$$
The integral logarithm term then becomes
$$I\approx\log\left(
\dfrac{H\left(r_{m}\right)+\varepsilon \left(\dfrac{{\rm d}H}{{\rm d}r}\right)_{r=r_{m}}}{H\left(r_{m}\right)-\varepsilon \left(\dfrac{{\rm d}H}{{\rm d}r}\right)_{r=r_{m}}}
\right),
$$
and by dividing the numerator and denominator by $H\left(r_{m}\right)$, we get
$$
I\approx\log\left(
\dfrac{1+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{H(r)} \dfrac{{\rm d}H(r)}{{\rm d}r}}{1-\dfrac{\varepsilon}{H(r)}\dfrac{{\rm d}H(r)}{{\rm d}r}}
\right)_{r=r_{m}}.
$$
If we now use the binomial expansion of the relation $(1+\varepsilon x)/(1-\varepsilon\, x)\approx 1+2\varepsilon\, x$,
this relation becomes
$$\,
I\approx\log\left(
1+\dfrac{2\varepsilon}{H(r)}\dfrac{{\rm d}H(r)}{{\rm d}r}
\right)_{r=r_{m}}\approx
\left(
\dfrac{2\varepsilon}{H(r)}\dfrac{{\rm d}H(r)}{{\rm d}r}\right)_{r=r_{m}}
$$
where we have used the series expansion $\log(1+\varepsilon\, x)\approx \varepsilon\, x$.
We have now to differentiate $H(r)$ to get
$$
\dfrac{{\rm d}H(r)}{{\rm d}r}=\dfrac{1}{h}\left[   \dfrac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+h^2}} +1 \right].
$$
The approximate expression for the integral, namely, $$I\approx\left(
\dfrac{2\varepsilon}{H(r)}\dfrac{{\rm d}H(r)}{{\rm d}r}\right)_{r=r_{m}},$$
then reduces to
$\dfrac{2\varepsilon}{\sqrt{r_{m}^2+h^2}+r_{m}}\left[\dfrac{r_{m}+\sqrt{r_{m}^2+h^2}}{\sqrt{r_{m}^2+h^2}}\right]$, and on cancelling terms in the numerator and denominator, we recover the expression you were looking to obtain, namely,
$$
I\approx\dfrac{r_{2}-r_{1}}{\sqrt{r_{m}^2+h^2}},
$$
when we use the defined quantities $\varepsilon = r_{2}-r_{1}$ and $r_{m}=\left(r_{1}+r_{2}\right)/2$.

This has now prompted me to read Hutton's paper. I guess Playfair also provided input into Maskelyne's problem a few years later. Has anyone retraced Hutton's approximations with the more accurate logarithmic expressions to see how accurate his results were?

**Addendum**
The simple result for the OP's calculus result of Hutton's approximation,
used in the calculation of the mountain Schiehallion's attraction on a plumb line, suggests that a more economic derivation was lurking in the background.

The integral $I\,$ can be written as
$$I=\left[F(r+\varepsilon)-F(r-\varepsilon)\right]_{r=r_{m}},\quad\text{where}$$
$$F(r)=\log[H(r)]\quad\text{ and }\quad H(r)=\dfrac{1}{h}\left\{\sqrt{r^2+h^2}+r\right\}.  $$
If the integral is written as
$$ I=2\varepsilon\left[\dfrac{F(r+\varepsilon)-F(r-\varepsilon)}{2\varepsilon}\right]_{r=r_{m}},  $$
the quantity in brackets is the central difference representation
of the differential ${\rm d}F(r)/{\rm d}r$ when $\varepsilon\ll r_{m}$.
Thus $I\approx 2\varepsilon\left[{\rm d}F(r)/{\rm d}r\right]_{r=r_{m}}$, and using the definition $F(r) =\log\left[H(r)\right]$ we recover the OP's result. The central difference operator is known to be accurate to the second order in $\varepsilon$, and if we expand the function $F$ in the numerator in a Taylor series, we get
$$I\approx 2\varepsilon\left[\dfrac{\left(F+\varepsilon F' +\tfrac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2 F''+\tfrac{1}{6}\varepsilon^3 F'''\right)-
\left(F-\varepsilon F' +\tfrac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2 F''-\tfrac{1}{6}\varepsilon^3 F'''\right)}{2\varepsilon}\right]_{r=r_{m}},$$ or
$$I\approx 2\varepsilon F'\left(r_{m}\right) +\tfrac{1}{3}\varepsilon^3 F'''\left(r_{m}\right)\approx \dfrac{2\varepsilon}{\left(r_{m}^2+h^2\right)^{1/2}}
+\dfrac{\varepsilon^3 \left(2 r_{m}^2-h^2\right)}{3\left(r_{m}^2+h^2\right)^{5/2}}.
$$
This shows that Hutton's geometric and the OP's calculus representations
of the plumb bob attraction are accurate to the second order in $\varepsilon$, since third order terms are required in order to affect the result. If the mean radius to the element is chosen as $r_{m}=h/\sqrt{2}$, the preceding result shows that Hutton's calculation would have been correct
to the fourth order of small quantities, since then the next term, $2\varepsilon^{5}F^{'''''}/5!\,$, would be needed to affect Hutton's result.

**Edit**

I have just found an expansion agreeing with the preceding result on page 597 of the 1856 paper by Henry James, *On the deflection of the plumb-line at Arthur's Seat, and the mean density of the earth*, Proceedings of the Royal Society, Vol. **146**, pages 591-606, https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rstl.1856.0029, where R.E. Clarke computes the attraction formula as
$$A=\rho h\left(\sin\theta_{2}-\sin\theta_{1}  \right)\left[ \dfrac{\left(r_{2}-r_{1}\right)}{\left(r_{m}^2+h^2\right)^{1/2}}+\dfrac{\left(r_{2}-r_{1}\right)^3}{24}\dfrac{2r_{m}^2-h^2}{\left(r_{m}^2+h^2\right)^{5/2}}  \right], $$
which agrees with preceding result on putting $\varepsilon=\left(r_{2}-r_{1}\right)/2.$

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you very much!!

If I understand your derivation correctly, the result holds even if the second assumption, i.e., $h \ll \frac{r_1 + r_2}{2}$, isn't true. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The logarithm expansion only requires that $2\varepsilon x \ll 1$ or that $r_{2}-r_{1} \ll \sqrt{r_{m}^2+h^2}.$

Comment: Yes. The logarithm expansion only requires that $2\varepsilon x \ll 1$ or that $r_{2}-r_{1} \ll \sqrt{r_{m}^2+h^2}.$ No restrictions on $h$ are required.